# Maven Plugin - attach artifact to the root on a multi-module project

Tags: java, maven, plugins, artifactory

I am building a Java Maven Plugin that is supposed to attach a file to the root project. This is done on the last project by the reactor order to make sure all files were compiled and ready to be picked up. The root project is always built first.
In other words, each project generates a file in it's target directory and at the end I want to combine file contents from each project into a single file and attach it as an artifact to the multi-module root project. Phew... This plugin is used in *compile* phase. And the artifact is attached using:

```java
private void attachArtifact() throws MojoExecutionException {
    String docExtension = "html"; // It can be any extension

    MavenProject rootProject = mavenSession.getTopLevelProject();
    projectHelper.attachArtifact(rootProject, docExtension, "doc-classifier", new File("target/files/info.html"));
    // File with relative path is generated under root project
    // Expecting artifact to be attached to the root project...
}
```

The plugin is skipped on intermediary modules and works only on last project (by reactor order). What I observed is that when I use *mavenProject* (i.e. currently building project) instead of *.getTopLevelProject()*, the artifact is successfully attached and performing a clean install causes this file to appear on local .m2 repository.

But if I try to attach the file to the root project (while execution is on the last child module), it does not get copied to the local .m2 repo. I suppose I do not have a way to attach an artifact to already built project? How can I overcome this?

Comment: The whole approach sounds like a bad idea. If you want to build an artifact from a list of other modules, add an additional module to build and deploy that artifact and make sure it depends on the other modules.

Comment: It is not an option when there are multiple repositories. I wanted to create a common plugin that could be used on different repos

Comment: `to attach a file to the root project.` ... the root project does not have code in it ... and only a single artifact which is the pom itself. Can you please exaplain exactly what kind of problem you are trying to solve? I don't understand your comment either... where is the relationship to repositories?

Comment: if you have multiple such projects in different git repos, you need to add a module to all of them. Building a plugin like you said will probably not work.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone stumps upon this problem. Here is a possible solution:

Firstly, the plugin must run on **'install'** phase. When plugin runs on the first project which is the top level in a multimodule project, create an empty file and attach it to that project. This file will get published to the artifactory. At the end, when the plugin is run on last submodule, you have to get the attached artifacts of the top level project and locate that file inside the artifactory (either local .m2 or another artifactory environment). Once you find it, you can **replace initial file** with the actual one.

In other words, you create a mock file and attach it as an artifact to the top level project. It gets published to the artifactory on **install** phase. Then it gets replaced with the real one in that artifactory. Attaching file to the root project, allows Artifactory management systems to see this file on deployment.

This allows having a single plugin that can collect the generated data from all submodules and produce an artifact for the root project at the end.

PS: You do not want to delete an artifact for a project that was already built. This will cause problems with Artifactory deployment later on.